# How to catch-up named mercurial branch from default branch without merging the two into one?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have two branches in mercurial..

```
default    named
|r1
|r2
|r3 --------         named branch created here.
|            |r4
|            |r5
| r6         |
|            |r7
|            |
-----------> | r8    How do I achieve this catch-up?
|            |
```

I want to update the named branch from default, but I'm not ready to merge the branches yet. How do I achieve this?

Edit:

Additionally, what would the operation be using the GUI?
Is it.. right-click r6, merge with..., r8,... then what? commit to named branch?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`hg merge default` from your named branch.

Comment: Thanks - what about in the GUI (tortoise hg?)

Comment: For TortoiseHg, you want to update to `r8`, then right-click on `r6 (default)` and select "Merge with local..." in the context menu. This will bring the changes from `default` into your `named` branch, since you are sitting there.